# How to read text files using ICU4J?

Tags: java, icu4j

I have to read text file using ICU4J, generally we use `BufferedReader` to read text file, but I am new to ICU4J. Can anyone suggest me how to read text files using ICU4J?

Comment: What's wrong with reading text files using BufferedReader?

Comment: take a look at this url : http://icu-project.org/icu4jdemos.html

Comment: Please tell us what you tried. What research you have done, what it turned up, what you are still missing.

Comment: Hi yole...We use BufferReader in Java ,but requirement is I have to read text file data through ICU4J API

Comment: are you working on `jdk older then 1.6` and looking for support of `UNICODE` or you need it in `android` either way you need to be specific about the actual problem because `icu4j` is a big `api`

Comment: @AsteriskNinja Hi Asterisk...I am working on jdk 1.5 but I have to use jdk 1.6 or 1.7 version for my project.

Comment: @Rani in `JDK1.8` or above then you don't need to use `icu4j` as you will get inbuilt support for all feature that `icu4j` will provide